# Checking if a value exists in an array of structs within a struct

Tags: go, iteration, lookup, iterable

Supposing I have two structs. StructA, and StructB which contains an array of StructA's. How am I able to loop through a StructB and check the value of a variable in the StructA's within it?

```
type StructA struct {
    varA string
    varB string
    varC string
}    


type StructB struct {
    foo  []StructA
}
```

Comment: You might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926303/iterate-through-a-struct-in-go to see another pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Struct is not iterable in Go. Also you want to iterate thorough a `foo` attribute not through a multiple `StructB` fields. Therefore you should iterate through a slice which is an attribute of the struct. And then just check for equation to find a desired value or determine that it is not there.

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-a1naLobb-):

```
target := "C"
a := StructB{[]StructA{StructA{"A", "B", "C"}}}
for _, i := range a.foo {
    if target == i.varA {
        fmt.Println(i.varA)
    } else if target == i.varB {
        fmt.Println(i.varB)
    } else if target == i.varC {
        fmt.Println(i.varC)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("None of above")
    }
}
```

Go is pretty explicit and tricks seldom give a real profit.

Comment: "Struct is not iterable in Go." Reflection let one to iterate over a struct fields.

Comment: @WilliamPoussier, yes it is true, but does it help when @j0ykls1cCMbTWfD1 has a single field `foo` and wants to iterate through it?