# Iterate through a go struct to get a csv string

Tags: go

I have a struct representing a dataset that I need to write to a CSV file as a time-series data. This is what I have so far.

```
type DataFields struct {
    Field1 int,
    Field2 string,
    ...
    Fieldn int
}

func (d DataFields) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v,%v,...,%v", Field1, Field2,..., Fieldn)
}
```

Is there a way I can iterate through the members of the struct and construct a string object using it?

Performance is not really an issue here and I was wondering if there was a way I could generate the string without having to modify the `String()` function if the structure changed in the future.

EDITED to add my change below:

This is what I ended up with after looking at the answers below.

```
func (d DataFields) String() string {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(d)
    var csvString string
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        csvString = fmt.Sprintf("%v%v,", csvString, v.Field(i).Interface())
    }

    return csvString
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv

Comment: The final version you posted has a trailing comma in the CSV representation. This was a problem for me, so I replaced the single line within the `for` loop with:
`if i == 0 { formatString = "%v%v" } else { formatString = "%v,%v" } csvString = fmt.Sprintf(formatString, csvString, v.Field(i).Interface())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926303/iterate-through-a-struct-in-go) answer explains how to use it to loop though a struct and get the values.

This is the example the author uses on the other answer:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    x := struct{Foo string; Bar int }{"foo", 2}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    values := make([]interface{}, v.NumField())

    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        values[i] = v.Field(i).Interface()
    }

    fmt.Println(values)
}
```

You can see it working on the [go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/gSnZ8mLll-).

Comment: Great. This answer was perfect. I was converting the Value field to a String directly like so `v.Field(i).String()` but I was not getting the actual string representation I was looking for.

I am guessing the String() was getting invoked on the Value receiver if the underlying concrete type was not a String. Is this expected?

Comment: @PradeepVaradharajan It is expected. Take a look at [package fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) for ways to format the fields and you can use `fmt.Sprintf` to convert them to string, Maybe `%v` the default go syntax representation for the value works for you.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the `reflect` package. There is a [`Value.Field(int) Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Field) method that might be usefull to you. You would essentially first call [`ValueOf(interface{}) Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) with your DataFields, and then have a simple loop calling `Field(int) Value` on the `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use [code generation](https://blog.golang.org/generate) which would generate a serializer code for you.

The trade-offs are:

- Codegen is more compilcated in that it, most of the time, relies
  on running an external program (though this could be made simpler by
  employing `go run` as it's supposed to be always available).

  Every time you make a change to your data type adding or removing
  a field which has to be serialized, you need to run `go generate`
  to regenerate the serializer code.

  On the flip side the resulting code is fast and robust,
  and the changes to the data type are usually seldom enough.
- Reflection is simpler in that it does not require thinking about
  regenerating the code.

  On the flip side, the code which uses `reflect` is usually ugly and quite hard to understand.  And of course it incurs runtime performance penalty.