# How to call func on a Struct instance after storing in list

Tags: list, go, struct, func

I tried searching, but can't find how to do this.
I want to take instances of my struct and store them in a list, then iterate over them and call a function on them.

```
type comicBook struct {
    Title     string
    Writer    string
    Artist    string
    Publisher string
    Year      int
    Pages     int
    Grade     float32
}
func (c comicBook) PrintInfo() {
    fmt.Println(c.Title, "written by", c.Writer, "drawn by", c.Artist, "published by", c.Publisher, "in", c.Year)
    fmt.Println("Pages:", c.Pages)
    fmt.Println("Grade:", c.Grade)
}
```

This works fine.

```
c := comicBook.NewComicBook(
        "Mr. GoToSleep",
        "Tracey Hatchet",
        "Jewel Tampson",
        "DizzyBooks Publishing Inc.",
        1997,
        14,
        6.5,
    )

c.PrintInfo()

c2 := comicBook.NewComicBook("Epic Vol. 1",
        "Ryan N. Shawn",
        "Phoebe Paperclips",
        "DizzyBooks Publishing Inc.",
        2013, 160, 9.0)

c2.PrintInfo()
```

Storing them in a list does not.

```
comicBookList := list.New()
    comicBookList.PushBack(c)
    comicBookList.PushBack(c2)

    fmt.Println("\nNow from a list!\n")

    for comic := comicBookList.Front(); comic != nil; comic = comic.Next() {
        comic.Value.PrintInfo()
    }
```

This fails with **comic.Value.PrintInfo undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)**

Comment: You may want to check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926303/iterate-through-the-fields-of-a-struct-in-go .

Comment: What list type are you using? And why are you using it instead of just using a slice?

Comment: @Adrian I am just learning Go, coming from C#. I had expected List to be a basic container, I was not aware of slices yet. The answer icza gave cleared up my issues.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the official docs then. Take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1), which covers all the language basics (including slices). Also read [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), which covers fundamentals as far as how to think about and write good Go code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`container/list`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/) is not "generic" and operates on `interface{}` values. To get "typed" values out of it, you have to use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

```
for comic := comicBookList.Front(); comic != nil; comic = comic.Next() {
    comic.Value.(comicBook).PrintInfo()
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/65BgfXs5vPb).

But you shouldn't use [`container/list`](https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/) in the first place.

Instead use a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types). Slices are generic (with the help of the compiler):

```
var books []comicBook
```

To add a value to the slice, use the builtin [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append):

```
b := comicBook.NewComicBook(...)
books = append(books, b)
```

To iterate over the slice, use `for range`:

```
for _, b := range books {
    b.PrintInfo()
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/A1b-0Vi-wuS).

Comment: Thank you. This makes much more sense than the list approach.

Comment: I'm actually having issues implementing this. The comicBook struct is in another file(just to try to work through managing imports as well) and since its lower case, it's not exported. I tried making it capital and doing 
var comicBookList []comicBook.ComicBook
but that is erroring on the next line that comicBook.ComicBook has no field or method append.

Comment: @galamdring `append()` is not a method, it's a function. Please check again how you use it: `books = append(books, b)`

Answer (score 0):

@icza's answer is the best approach. That said, you can use type assertion.

```
for comic := comicBookList.Front(); comic != nil; comic = comic.Next() {
    realComic, ok := comic.Value.(comicBook)
    if !ok {
        panic("this would error anyway, but good for visibility")
    }
    realComic.PrintInfo()
}
```